# Regex string mismatch with pipe

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex

```
var catalogueHrefRegex = /\/automobiles\/(cr)|(ts$)|(zs)|(ax)|(wx)$/;
```

I am testing this against a url, for example

```
var href = "xxx/compare/ax?model=xxx";
```

I run the following code

```
catalogueHrefRegex.test(href)
```

I expected it to return false but it returns true. I am trying to URLs like

```
/automobiles/cr/...
/automobiles/ts/...
/automobiles/zs/...
/automobiles/ax/...
/automobiles/wx/...
```

I have the $ at the end of ts because I don't want to match 'automobiles/tsx'
I tried the following but none of them worked as expected

```
/\/automobiles\/((cr)|(ts$)|(zs)|(ax)|(wx))$/
/\/automobiles\/*(cr)|(ts$)|(zs)|(ax)|(wx)*$/
```

I am not good with regex, so my attempts were after some googling. I am suspecting the way I set up the pipes were wrong or the grouping is incorrect because when I try 'cr', it works as expected but I am not sure how to group the cr/ts/zs/ax/wx so that it says match automobiles/ cr or ts or ...

http://jsfiddle.net/WdXXx/

What is the correct regex for my desired results? Thank you for your time

Comment: This one should be working as you expected it to: `/\/automobiles\/((cr)|(ts$)|(zs)|(ax)|(wx))$/` (it's the second regex you mention in your question). See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WdXXx/1/).

Comment: @Jerry yes it does return false, however that regex does not match automobiles/XX either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple of issues. First, an alternation applies to the entire group that contains it. Secondly, `$` matches the end of the input string (or the end of the line in multi-line mode). So your first regex:

```
/\/automobiles\/(cr)|(ts$)|(zs)|(ax)|(wx)$/
```

will match a literal `/automobiles/cr` or a literal `ts` followed by the end of the string or a literal `zs` or a literal `ax` or a literal `wx` followed by the end of the string.

I suspect you want a pattern like this instead:

```
/\/automobiles\/(cr|ts|zs|ax|wx)\//
```

This will match a literal `/automobiles/` followed by a literal `cr`, `ts`, `zs`, `ax`, or `wx` followed by a literal `/`.

I dropped the `$` because in your example you used `/...`, implying that there are other characters following the final `/`.

You can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5C/automobiles%5C/%28cr%7Cts%7Czs%7Cax%7Cwx%29%5C/&input=/automobiles/cr/...%0A/automobiles/ts/...%0A/automobiles/zs/...%0A/automobiles/ax/...%0A/automobiles/wx/...%0A%0A%0Axxx/compare/ax?model=xxx%0Axxx/compare/cr?model=xxx).

Comment: In regards to the `(ts$)` I think the OP wants to match something like:  `/automobiles/ts`, but not: `/automobiles/ts/1`.

Comment: @CodingGorilla OP stated "*I don't want to match 'automobiles/tsx'*", which my pattern does not match.

Comment: But based on this attempt: `/\/automobiles\/*(cr)|(ts$)|(zs)|(ax)|(wx)*$/` I think if it's not `ts` at the end he wants it to continue to match (and capture) to the end of the string.  I think he wants something like: `\/automobiles\/((cr|ts$|zs|ax|wx)\/.*)$` (that's not tested, trying to get the idea across)

Comment: @CodingGorilla That could be the intent. The question is not entirely clear. The way I understood the the question (based largely on the examples) OP is trying to match just part of a URL, where there may be other characters following the matched text.

Comment: Yes the answer did exactly as I needed. I am not good with regex so the attempts I had might be a bit misleading